# How do I draw a curved 3D line in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

I want to have a curved 3D line like so:

[image]

As you can see the behind of the line has a dark yellow/orange color, and the front side has a blue color, also the line is curved on the Z axis, how do I achieve this in Inkscape? How do I make a line thats curved on the Z axis and then color the front and behind respectively?

I know how to make a 2D curved line using the ellipse tool, but how do I draw a line like this?

Comment: Don't think of it as drawing an object in three dimensions, just think of it as drawing shapes that combine to give the impression of something three dimensional. This is just two flat shapes, each of which can be drawn from basic curves.

Comment: @Westside Yes, never taught of that , good idea , BTW , what tool do i use to get those curves ? brzieer pen ?

Comment: You could freehand draw it with curves if you're good with the pen tool, but personally I would construct it using sections of circles. I'm not an inkscape user though so I'm not sure on the specifics for that software.

Comment: @Westside did't want to do it the freehand way , tryed circles and got close enuf , but still not perfect. Thanks for the tips , I'll see how i can perfect this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Curves like this can be drawn with the Pen tool. Use only a few nodes to be able keep the shapes easily smoothly curved.

[image]

The left shows the paths without fills. The overlap is no harm because it will be hidden. It's actually useful if you export as PNG. Exactly fitting seams in PNG exports become partially transparent.

The snapping helps to make the parts to fit. The node tool is for minor tweaks. Once well practiced, one can draw the fitting shapes on the fly. In the long run it really pays off to learn how the Pen tool works.

NOTE: The hardest part is to invent the needed shapes. This case seems deceptively easy, because I had your screenshot to watch. Explore plenty of existing works to develop a vocabulary for representing the things.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and thanks you very much fo r the great advice , which otherwise i would only know through alot of painful trail and error haha :D . Great answer .